# how do I get keyboard to implement arguments correctly?

Tags: python, tkinter, keyboard-python

I keep getting the error:
`TypeError: runcmd() missing 1 required positional argument: 'inp'`
while trying to use keyboard.add_hotkey,

```
def runcmd(inp):
    text = inp
    kb.remove_hotkey("enter")
    if text == "help":
        from tkinter import messagebox
        messagebox.showinfo("commands","switchto <file> | opens <file> in the main editor\n")

def open_cmd_pallete():
    top= tk.Toplevel(root)
    top.geometry("750x30")
    top.title("command pallete")
    inp = tk.Entry(top)
    inp.pack()
    kb.add_hotkey("enter",runcmd,args=(inp.get())) # issue here
```

and whenever I try to change it to `kb.add_hotkey("enter",runcmd(inp.get()))` then it throws another error, so how do i fix this?

Comment: Where is `open_cmd_pallete` supposed to get `inp` from? Because it's not a function argument.

Comment: `inp.get()` activates immediately! Try `inp.get`.

Comment: `kb.add_hotkey("enter",runcmd,args=(inp.get))` now returns  
```callback = lambda callback=callback: callback(*args)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: __main__.runcmd() argument after * must be an iterable, not method
```

Comment: I'm not sure `args=(inp.get)` will work, because it would have to know that is a function to be called later, instead of an actual object to be passed as the arg directly.

Comment: I don't understand the basic error.  You're providing _something_ as an arg, even if it isn't the right thing, so I don't see why it would complain that the `inp` argument is missing altogether...

Comment: fixed, just initialised `inp` as a global variable. Python accepted that

Answer (score 0):

for anyone who *might* (although very rare) come back to this. All you need to do is change the variable to a global,
so in wherever (`def`), just change it to

```
def foo1():
    var1 = inp

def foo2():
    global var1
    ...
```

and it works

Comment: Should it be `global inp` based on your comment to your own question?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to pass a *tuple* to `args=` instead.  Second you should pass the reference of `inp` instead of `inp.get()` because there is nothing input when `kb.add_hotkey("enter",runcmd,args=(inp.get()))` is executed

Updated code:

```py
def runcmd(inp):
    text = inp.get()
    ...

def open_cmd_pallete():
    ...
    kb.add_hotkey("enter", runcmd, args=(inp,)) # used tuple
```